# Merge two SELECTs containing JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two straightforward SELECT queries left-joining the same table in a MySQL DB:

```
SELECT uID, externaluID, COUNT(editID) AS editCount 
FROM users
LEFT JOIN (edits
    INNER JOIN posts 
    ON postRefID = postID AND editAuthorID <> authorID AND isa = 0)
ON editAuthorID = uID
GROUP BY uID
ORDER BY uID;

SELECT uID, externaluID, COUNT(posts.postID) AS postCount, SUM(value)
FROM users
LEFT JOIN (posts
    LEFT JOIN usrR ON posts.postID = usrR.postID)
ON authorID = uID
GROUP BY authorID
ORDER BY uID;
```

So far so good. Now I want to merge these queries. My approach was

```
SELECT uID, externaluID, COUNT(editID) AS editCount, COUNT(P2.postID) AS postCount, SUM(rateValue)
FROM users
LEFT JOIN (edits
    INNER JOIN posts AS P1
    ON postRefID = P1.postID AND editAuthorID <> P1.authorID AND isa = 0)
ON editAuthorID = uID
LEFT JOIN (posts AS P2
    LEFT JOIN usrR ON P2.postID = usrR.postID)
ON P2.authorID = uID
GROUP BY P2.authorID, uID
ORDER BY uID;
```

but it returns wrong results. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You group by different columns, hard to merge...

Comment: (1) You are getting a cartesian product for each `uid`.  (2) Use column aliases so we know where the columns are coming from.  (3) Sample data and results help convey both your problem and the issue with your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT u1.uID, u1.externaluID, COUNT(e1.editID) AS editCount, u2.postCount, u2.sumValue
FROM users u1 
LEFT JOIN (edits INNER JOIN posts 
        ON postRefID = postID AND editAuthorID <> authorID AND isa = 0) as e1
    ON e1.editAuthorID = u1.uID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT uID, externaluID, COUNT(posts.postID) AS postCount, SUM(value) as sumValue
    FROM users
    LEFT JOIN (posts
        LEFT JOIN usrR ON posts.postID = usrR.postID)
    ON authorID = uID
    GROUP BY authorID
    ORDER BY uID) as u2 on u1.uID = u2.uID 
GROUP BY u1.uID,u2.postCount, u2.sumValue
ORDER BY u1.uID
```

Comment: MySQL didn't like `as e1` in line 4 but after removing it, the query delivered the correct results. Thanks!